# How do I create a Mule ESB Service to HTTP POST using name/value pairs?

Tags: web-services, http, esb, endpoints, mule

I need to create a mule service that will POST data to a web service that expects name/value pairs (not xml), then process the XML response from that service. I cannot find a good example on how to prep the payload for an http POST.

Can someone provide some insight or examples?

What I have so far is (I don't know if 'PathToTransformerClass' is needed):

```
    <service name="myService">
        <inbound>
            <vm:inbound-endpoint path="myService.request" synchronous="true">
                <custom-transformer class="PathToTransformerClass" />
            </vm:inbound-endpoint>
        </inbound>
        <outbound>
            <pass-through-router>
                <http:outbound-endpoint address="URIofWebServiceToPostTo" method="POST" synchronous="true">
                    <response-transformers>
                        <custom-transformer class="PathToClassToProcessTheResponse" />
                    </response-transformers>
                </http:outbound-endpoint>
            </pass-through-router>
        </outbound>
    </service>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following might be helpful: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.mule.user/29342

I can't find any examples either, but it looks like the built-in [HTTP transformers](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE2USER/HTTP+Transport) are

> http-response-to-object-transformer   A
>   transformer that converts an HTTP
>   response to a Mule Message. The
>   payload may be a String, stream, or
>   byte array.
>
> http-response-to-string-transformer
>     Converts an HTTP response payload
>   into a string. The headers of the
>   response will be preserved on the
>   message.
>
> object-to-http-request-transformer
>     This transformer will create a valid
>   HTTP request using the current message
>   and any HTTP headers set on the
>   current message.
>
> message-to-http-response-transformer
>     This transformer will create a valid
>   HTTP response using the current
>   message and any HTTP headers set on
>   the current message.

object-to-http-request-transformer might be your best bet; perhaps you can create a map of key-value pairs and then convert that into URL encoded form?  Not sure but hopefully this gives you some things to Google.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about how to take XML and create key value pairs to send out via HTTP? For that you can use an XLST transformer where in the XSL you set the method output to be text.

Answer (score 0):

1) Let `variables=<map><entry><string>idEvent_Type</string><string>1</string></entry></map>&options=user:admin`

be the Map body to post as HTTP request.

2) URL encode it (eg. using http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)

which produce :

```
variables%3D%3Cmap%3E%3Centry%3E%3Cstring%3EidEvent_Type%3C%2Fstring%3E%3Cstring%3E1%3C%2Fstring%3E%3C%2Fentry%3E%3C%2Fmap%3E%26options%3Duser%3Aadmin
```

3) then create a Mule set-payload transformer :

```
<set-payload value="variables%3D%3Cmap%3E%3Centry%3E%3Cstring%3EidEvent_Type%3C%2Fstring%3E%3Cstring%3E1%3C%2Fstring%3E%3C%2Fentry%3E%3C%2Fmap%3E%26options%3Duser%3Aadmin
" doc:name="Set playload"/>
```

4) then create a Mule HTTP endpoint :

```
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="..." port="..." path="..." user="..." password="..." contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" doc:name="POSTHTTPRequest"/>
```

and it works

Answer (score 0):

Maybe U can give a try using Object-to-http-request-transformer as this transformer will create a valid HTTP request using the message currently received and any HTTP headers set on the current message.
Have never tried it, but that is the only transformer I can get in my mind after reading ur query...hope it works.. :D

Comment: you can post your code it will be useful to know your idea